# Netbeans RCP - duplicate third party jar in "clusters/modules/ext" folder

Tags: netbeans, maven, maven-nbm

I have two  `Cluster` in my `Netbeans RCP` project (`Cluster A`, and `Cluster B`).

Module  `M-A`  in Cluster A, has dependency to Module `M-B`  in Cluster B.    `M-A  --->  M-B`

besides this, both modules (M-A and M-B) have dependency to a `third party jar ( tp.jar )`.

when i'm building my suite,  I have  tp.jar in 2 different places (two cluster) :
`A/modules/ext/tp.jar`  and  `B/modules/ext/tp.jar`

in consequence netbeans class loader finding 2 jar files in the class and is not able to load the any of them.

Any idea have to solve this issue ?

PS: I'm using Maven 2.X. and nbm plugin.

Regards,

Mohammad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper module for your library (`tp.jar`) and let both modules depend on the wrapper module.

You can read more about it at http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqWrapperModules

Comment: thanks for the solution. actually i'm using your solution currently. I was looking for a solution to get rid of this wrappers.